# Talend Subjobs and Sundry

Tags: talend

Trying to troubleshoot an existing Talend job with many iterations and sub-jobs created by a developer who is no longer with the company. Ran into an issue with subjobs and hoping someone here can answer.

I know by reading the documentation that OnSubjobOk10 indicates that the job will execute after #10 is complete. But in a workflow with no names, how I do know which is Subjob#10? Can I assume it is the one from where the job-job connection is made?

Thanks in advance,
Bee

Answer (score 0):

OnSubJobOK will make te next subjob work if the previous subjob finished without error, from [help.talend](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendDataIntegrationStudioUserGuide54EN/4.3.1+Connection+types):

> OnSubjobOK (previously Then Run): This link is used to trigger the
>   next subjob on the condition that the main subjob completed without
>   error. This connection is to be used only from the start component of
>   the Job.
>
> These connections are used to orchestrate the subjobs forming the Job
>   or to easily troubleshoot and handle unexpected errors.

Comment: Thanks for responding - guess I'm getting thrown-off by OnSubjobOK10 - where I'm expecting there to be a Subjob10, guess from your post and the documentation, it just means the previous job is THE sub-job 10